# Custom Button template xaml

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp

```
<Button Content="Reset" Click="ResetResalePrice_Click">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border>
                            <Image Source="Assets/Reset.png"/>

                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

Hey guys! I have been searching like crazy , how do I set the style to this button to act as a default button , I mean to change the background for example , to react on click , just like default template. I searched , but everywhere says that I should use  and it seems that there is no Triggers property. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1 : I just tried setting the content of the button to a border/grid/stackpanel and then set the image there but it looks horrible , a big gray square with an image in the middle.

EDIT 2: Well I just removed the brush for the background of the button , exactly what I wanted , but I there any way I can add a Zoom effect?

Comment: not sure exactly what your end result is but if it's anything like what I think you're doing try setting button borderthickness, minheight and minwidth properties to 0 and see if that moves you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger property is not available on Windows Store App, if you need something similar like trigger, ref to this doc: [Button styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709909.aspx), there are several visual states and modify into them will bring you the surprise.

For example if you need click trigger, look into the "Pressed" visual state.